# scripting a button to make a new sheet with a specific name, and autofilling the selected cell + 1 above and 4 more cells to the right

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been struggling for a while now to make a script, which can locate the selected cell, and copy text into it.
My script should, in the end be able to make an extra sheet with a specific name and autofill 5 columns to the right of a seleceted cell (including the selected cell) + 1 merged cell above.
All the autofilled code will refer to the new sheets.
All this should be done by pushing a button after selecting the desired location.

I've been copying text from different websites' Q&A, youtube videos and google apps scripts, and this is what I came up with so far.:

```
function buttonClick() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var naame = Browser.inputBox("Test type / name");

  try {
    ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(naame));
  } 

  catch (e) {
    ss.insertSheet(naame);
  }

  var activeRange = ss.getActiveRange();
  var cell, cellValue, cellFormula;

  // iterate through all cells in the active range
  for (var cellRow = 1; cellRow <= activeRange.getHeight(); cellRow++) {
    for (var cellColumn = 1; cellColumn <= activeRange.getWidth(); cellColumn++) {
      cell = activeRange.getCell(cellRow, cellColumn);

      /**
      Here I'm trying different things to copy some text to the selected cell.
      //cell.copyTo(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,6));
      SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange(1.6).copyTo(cell);
      */    
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: I can't get it to paste / copyTo the text (naame) in the selected cell.